# NullPointerException when I try to add a Node to BinarySearchTree

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, nodes

I'm getting a `pointer exception error`, it's saying my **root** is `null`. But I know it's null! I thought the way I had programmed it is so that if the root is null, it adds a node in that space.

```
Printing out the list...
73,M&M's Fun size
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Node.add(Node, Entry)" because "this.root" is null
        at BinarySearchTree.add(BinarySearchTree.java:71)
        at BinarySearchTree.main(BinarySearchTree.java:26)
```

Here is my main snippet -

```
          File myObj = new File("halloween calories.txt");
          Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
          Integer.parseInt(myReader.nextLine());
    
          BinarySearchTree bst = new BinarySearchTree();
          
          System.out.println("Printing out the list...");
          while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            String string = myReader.nextLine();
            if (string.equals("END")) break;
            String[] parts = string.split(",");
            int part1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
            String part2 = parts[1];
            Entry a = new Entry(part1, part2);
            System.out.println(a.key + "," + a.value);

            bst.add(a);

          }
```

Where I read in a file, split it, and add the two halves as an entry with an `int` key and `String` value.
I need to call a method from my Node from my BinarySearchTree class
This is the BinarySearchTree class method

```
    public void add(Entry entry) {
        /*Adds the key to the correct position in the BST. If the key already
        exists, do nothing. So, basically, you are creating a proper-set of
        numbers.*/
        root.add(root, entry);
        
    }
```

Thhis is from my Node class.

```
    public  Node add(Node current, Entry entry) {
       /*Adds the key to the correct position in the BST. If the key already
        exists, do nothing.*/
        if (current == null) {
            current = new Node(entry);
        } else if (current.entry.key < entry.key) {
            // if current root data is greater than the new data then now process the left sub-tree
            add(current.left, entry);
        } else {
            // if current root data is less than the new data then now process the right sub-tree
            add(current.right, entry);
        } return current;
        
    }
```

I've been beating my head against the wall trying to figure this out, all the code I've googled looks identical to my own.

Having the same problem I think with the print function! I think I keep declaring the root as null but I have very specific parameters for this assignment which is part of the reason it's been so difficult for me. I actually managed to get it working perfectly by making the functions static, but my professor said I need to be calling on the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the corresponding fields of the `current` node after each recursive calls in the if statement.

```
public  Node add(Node current, int entry) {
   /*Adds the key to the correct position in the BST. If the key already
    exists, do nothing.*/
    if (current == null) {
        current = new Node(entry);
    } else if (current.entry.key < entry) {
        // if current root data is greater than the new data then now process the left sub-tree
        current.left = add(current.left, entry);
    } else {
        // if current root data is less than the new data then now process the right sub-tree
       current.right =  add(current.right, entry);
    } return current;

}
```